# Uniform stress toroidal pressure vessel shape

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure

For simply connected surfaces of revolution and uniform stress the shape is a hollow sphere.

What should the shape or thickness variation be for a hollow torus ( like an automobile inflated inner tube) in order that the stress be constant when pressurized/inflated?

Integration of equilibrium gives CMC constant mean curvature $=H$  minimal surfaces of revolution with ode for meridian as [Unduloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unduloid)

$$ \kappa_1+\kappa_2= 2 H $$

But this is not a toroidal unduloid.

Thanks in advance for literature whether any such doughnut shapes were built or derivation pointers on the topic.

Comment: The stress in an inflated hollow sphere isn't uniform; it's [much higher in the plane of the wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_vessel#Stress_in_thin-walled_pressure_vessels). Are you referring to an inflated shape? (Otherwise, how does the stress arise?) Do you mean the biaxial stress in the wall plane? Please clarify.

Comment: Also see [here](https://ap-st01.ext.exlibrisgroup.com/61RMIT_INST/upload/n2006070572.pdf?Expires=1657750116&Signature=twRQVL5rSklBGjHrO~KRWJNlF1FU1n5vsPMiOMOVlH7sZlT2mLuty0GASA1k8~y8RU9PVTD06xVQQPg37WNXbypJs4~BJFMK8LRtZ~yJVGmiXNZgU0JzClOEMaEt0ZLehisKMOspA4El5nLRMVn5mVWyepvEVzQeyY73fNSQClC4LboAzrpY-grhCv2QvTQG66MxEPQzUteQ7nv5JSn5H7r~ucVA8DO0unCUtJiDG6Cwz3Z~UNuoKgmcXZKgi2BOfs6PxSWiHp39YaMNdinI8RFc0Y1mkg~y~Gq-V6to7Gz62QwWYNmvBjdc7NaS7hU7jVkgTYG42Pyq-TXjWppYXQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ72OZCZ36VGVASIA) ("Optimisation of vessel shell thickness") and the associated references.

Comment: The linked article is Fowler et al., "[A review of toroidal composite pressure vessel optimisation and damage tolerant design for high pressure gaseous fuel storage](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360319916330336?via%3Dihub)," the first search result for `"constant stress" inflated hollow torus`.

Comment: Yes, the stress in walls of a bi-axially pressure loaded *steel or aluminum*  toroid (not composite construction) is to be uniform.